# 14.04 gnome-shell gnome-control-center screen does not work on desktop, why?

Tags: 14.04, gnome, screensaver, gnome-control-center

After hdd crash.

I decided to also install latest ubuntu 14.04.4 now. Kernel 3.19 (previously I was still using the older kernel).

After installing ubuntu I installed gnome-shell. I was again hit by the screen which does not switch off in despite the fact that by gnome-control-centre screen the screen off pause time is set.

More info about pc.

6 core (12 threads) intel processor asus mb 64 GB running ubunutu x86-64.
running as home server 24/24.

Basic answer posted below. It will let work the Brightness & Lock setting in gnome-shell. Like it works in unity.

Comment: What is the answer then?

Comment: At time why did You change my question ?

Comment: I changed it at 11:12:41 UTC on the 8th of October 2015 - half an hour ago. I removed the bad grammar and unnecessary commentary.

Comment: Ok the question was a bit to extensive with info. And grammar sorry english is not my native language.  But You where a bit fast by removing that an answer would follow since I was busy writing that.

Comment: Yeah, the reason for that was because you're meant to have the question and answer separated - and you don't need to say you're working on it - it's fine to have a time gap.

Comment: Yeah , that happens. The real main goal , is that if users are trying to find why the base function Brightness & Lock does not work in ubuntu 14.04 and gnome-shell.  (while it does work with unity) . You come to so what all answers, and a lot are really space. I just hope with this question and a first simple base (not hackish or tremendous work-around) answer, users drop on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `gnome-screensaver` daemon is not started. That is why using:
System Settings -> Brightness & Lock does not work with Gnome Shell on Ubuntu 14.04. It does with unity of course.

For gnome shell you need to search for Start-up Applications and create a new application with the following command:

```
/usr/bin/gnome-screensaver
```

That's all. Now System Settings-> Brightness & Lock will work after a reboot or login / logout.

The above will just switch off and or lock the screen depending on settings made. If you want a real screen-saver it will be more complicated.

You can use the same method as for unity with that. It would be nice if a person knowing the right straight answer to let work the gnome screensaver entertainment part to post it here .